# Combining slantsc and cfr-lm package

Tags: fonts, italic, small-caps, latin-modern, slanted

I am interest in italic and slanted small caps.

I found that slanted small caps are easily done with slantsc package, while italic small caps are provided by cfr-lm package.

Unfortunately, I think that these packages are little conflicting in without further configuration. What is the right order of import?

The order to solve it almost (but I need the first case) is here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}


\begin{document}
slanted:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textsl{\textsc{Slanted Small-caps}}
  \item \textsc{\textsl{Small-caps Slanted}}
\end{enumerate}

italic:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textit{\textsc{Italic Small-caps}}
  \item \textsc{\textit{Small-caps Italic}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 3):

`slantsc` is rather old (from 2012). In the last LaTeX release changes has been made to the font system to allow for slanted/italic small caps without tricks. So I would recommend to no longer use this package.

With a current LaTeX (`LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`) I get without `slantsc`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cfr-lm}


\begin{document}
slanted:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textsl{\textsc{Slanted Small-caps}}
  \item \textsc{\textsl{Small-caps Slanted}}
\end{enumerate}

italic:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textit{\textsc{Italic Small-caps}}
  \item \textsc{\textit{Small-caps Italic}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to compile it without this package but no satisfying result. I am using:`This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)` May I ask how did you install your latex version?

Comment: The version of the binary is not the important part. Check the log for the latex version. I updated to this latex version with the texlive manager, tlmgr.

Comment: But beside this: you shouldn't use cmr-lm with xelatex, it will change to an fontencoding not suitable for unicode engines.